# MVC 4 Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2015 /2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have just updated my developer machine and stupidly updated to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 at the same time. Since updating my MVC4 applications intellisense is saying "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context" along with ViewBag etc. I have searched and tried most of the things people have mentioned about the Web.Config Versions and NuGet etc. I even tried going up in .Net Versions to 4.6 which has made no difference. I have reopened it in Visual Stidio 2013 and the issue has migrated to there as well.

Any ideas where I should be looking? The application runs fine its just the intellisense.

Thanks

Chris